# How do websites like twitter parse return type in REST

Tags: rest

How does websites like Twitter structure their server side for APIs in which there can be multiple return types?

For ex: 
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update
In this link, you can find that their example resource url is "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json"

Using the ".json" extension, they differentiate between the return type. My questions basically is, if this is the method that they use, then do parse the url and get the extension using normal string manipulation, or is their a built in support in REST that is capable of doing so.
Also, is it better to have multiple APIs for multiple return types, or can there be a single API that can have multiple return types?

Comment: You will have to ask Twitter about how they do it.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, the specification JAX-RS provides the `@Produces` annotation. Setting

```
@Produces("application/json")
```

on a method will make this method match any request with the HTTP header

```
Accept: application/json
```

Obviously Twitter is doing something else. With JAX-RS you could use path matching.

```
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("/1.1/statuses/update.json")
```

could be the annotations for a method the prodcues `application/json` while

```
@Produces("application/xml")
@Path("/1.1/statuses/update.xml")
```

could be the annotations that produce `application/xml`.

I'd advise not to go the Twitter way of putting the content type into the URI. Instead use the proper HTTP tools of content negotiation with the HTTP headers `Accept` and `Content-Type`.